# Specifying the JSON names in response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to be able to specify the names used in the JSON response from my server.

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/search/forSearchPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Object>>> searchForFeaturedContent() {
    List<Account> nearbyAccounts = accountService.findClosestNearbyAccounts();
    List<Account> onlineAccounts = accountService.findOnlineAccounts();
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
    Page<Place> places = placeService.findTop10ByFeaturedTrue(pageable);
    List<Place> placesList = places.getContent();

    List<Object> accountsAndPlaces = new ArrayList<>();
    accountsAndPlaces.addAll(nearbyAccounts);
    accountsAndPlaces.addAll(onlineAccounts);
    accountsAndPlaces.addAll(placesList);

    // Create page out of this list
    Page<Object> pageOfAccountsAndPlaces = new PageImpl<>(accountsAndPlaces, pageable, accountsAndPlaces.size());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(objectPagedAssembler.toResource(pageOfAccountsAndPlaces), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This returns a response like this:

```
{
"_embedded" : {
    "places" : [...],
    "accounts" : [...],
    "_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href" : "http://staging-api.papped.co/accounts/search/forSearchPage"
    }
},
"page" : {
    "size" : 10,
    "totalElements" : 10,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
}
```

This groups all the accounts together and sticks them under the name "accounts". However, I  want to change it to look something like:

```
{
"_embedded" : {
    "places" : [...],
    "nearbyAccounts" : [...],
    "onlineAccounts" : [...], // <- See how these have been separated
    "_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href" : "http://staging-api.papped.co/accounts/search/forSearchPage"
    }
},
"page" : {
    "size" : 10,
    "totalElements" : 10,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
}
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to declare a class which will be serialized as expected.

```
public class MeaningfulNameHere {
    Collection<Account> nearbyAccount;
    Collection<Account> onlineAccount;
    Collection<Place> places;

    /* constructors and getters */
}
```

Instead of putting list of objects, return an instance of the given class. Depending on your serialization library you may need to add some anotations on your new type. Most probably, yours is Jackson and.will work as it.

Comment: How would this be made into a page?

Answer (score 0):

what is happening is that you are inadvertently concatenating the two  Account List together when you add them onto the accountsAndPlaces List.

Replace:

```
List<Account> nearbyAccounts = accountService.findClosestNearbyAccounts();
List<Account> onlineAccounts = accountService.findOnlineAccounts();
```

With:

```
List<NearByAccounts> nearbyAccounts = accountService.findClosestNearbyAccounts();
List<OnlineAccounts> onlineAccounts = accountService.findOnlineAccounts();
```

You will have to create the two new classes as well:

```
public class NearByAccount extends Account {}

public class OnlineAccounts extends Account {}
```

Comment: For some reasons the paged assembler treats them all as Accounts still and not separate classes, so this didn't work for me :/